# Spoof ip for my dad

Tags: networking, ip, spoofing

so i need to spoof my ip to mirror my dad's.

He has a webpage and e-buisness and its been compromised - basically, i need to take a look inside the dashboard.

He has had his ip whitelisted so using the url takes him to the dash asking for u/p (which i of course have).

Is there a way to do this using software or somehow - it's an 80 mile round trip to go in person.

Your thoughts appreciated.

Si

Comment: Actually just thought this through and i don't think it would be possible as where would the return data go.... Doh

Comment: Just use TeamViewer add your ip to the whitelist.

Comment: Any remote connect software works, or using VPN will work too if a VPN server is setup at your dads place.

Answer (score 4):

You can't spoof or mirror his IP without help from his ISP which is unlikely to be forthcoming.

You can, however, use TeamViewer or equivalent to log into a device on his LAN and then access the server that way.  In most home setups it can be any device on his LAN, not limited to his computer.

Comment: Or if he sets-up a VPN server at the location of his dad, and connects to it, redirecting all his traffic over the VPN, he will also have the IP address of his dad.